# Nginx routing ignores anything after path rule

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We are setting up nginx with kubernetes for formio. We need the .com/ to point to the api server, and the .com/files/ to point to the pdf server. Here is the ingress config:

```
  paths:
  - backend:
      serviceName: formio
      servicePort: 80
    path: /
  - backend:
      serviceName: formio-files
      servicePort: 4005
    path: /files/(.*)$
```

We have it setup that our PDFs are being stored in the path like /files/pdf/filename.
The issue is that whole path after /files/ also gets redirected to the PDF server, instead of just stopping at /files/

Comment: Basically if you have /files/pdf/<pdf_file> in your request you receive /pdf/<pd_file> on your pdf service?

Comment: Are you using the `rewrite-target` annotation?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? I didn't see any updates.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue and it was caused by the path regex which you set. First, you need to understand clearly about it. The path regex `/files/(.*)$` will match all the path `/files/...`, no matter what you add after `/files/`. So it redirects all the requests with path `/files/...`. If you only want to redirect the PDF requests to the path `/files/pdf/...`, the solution is set the path regex as `/files/pdf/(.*)$`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is we were using the azure cloud shell with bash to apply it. Would look like this:
'kubectl apply -f '
Bash was treating the $1 as a variable instead of writing it to the config, so rewrite-target would not work.
Saved the config as a YAML and applied that which fixed the problem.

Thanks for the help everyone